# How to implement method in the component class to service class

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesService} from '../courses.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  template:`
  <h2>Courses</h2>
  <input type="text" appAutoGrow />
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
      {{course }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" #newcourse />
  <button (click)="addCourses(newcourse.value)" >Add</button>
  `,
  providers: [CoursesService]
})

export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  courses;
   addCourses(newcourse: string){
     if(newcourse){          
     this.courses.push(newcourse);
     }
   }
  constructor(coursesService: CoursesService) { 
    this.courses = coursesService.getCourses();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This will work correctly, to add the elements into courses array and display it on the HTML as LI element, but what should I do to implement it into the service class (the `addCourses` function) I try many times to implement it with different code but failed.

and here is my service class code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class CoursesService {
    getCourses() {
        return ["course1", "course2", "course3"];
    }
  constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do something like this :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable()
    export class CoursesService {
        courses = ["course1", "course2", "course3"];
       addCourses(newcourse: string){
         this.courses.push(newcourse);
       }
        getCourses() {
            return this.courses;
        }
      constructor() { }
    }

export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  courses;
   addCourses(newcourse: string){
     if(newcourse){          
       this.coursesService.addCourses(newcourse);
     }
   }
  constructor(private coursesService: CoursesService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.courses = this.coursesService.getCourses();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one before, but the error log self.context.addcourse is not a function...

Comment: you forgot `private` keyword in the constructor, see the update

Comment: Thanks, bro. But your code still have a little problem, after change the code in ngOnInit() in to the Constructor , the code starts to work.